# How do I make privoxy block filters work for HTTPS websites?

Tags: https, privoxy

My filters work on HTTP websites, I have put this in my config file:

```
enforce-blocks 1
actionsfile blacklist.action
```

and `blacklist.action` contains

```
{ +block }
*facebook.com/tr/*
```

When I visit `facebook.com/tr/`, it loads the page like normal, unlike HTTP sites where I have put a filter. I have set both the HTTP and the HTTPS proxy in the proxy settings, so that's not the issue.

Comment: HTTPS is encrypted, so a proxy server can't change it.

Comment: You could try SSL interception, but it would require you to install a certificate from the proxy server that's intercepting and decrypting your HTTPS traffic. Also, it's pretty insecure.

Answer (score 0):

> **[4.15. How can Privoxy filter Secure (HTTPS) URLs?](https://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html#SSL)**
>
> If you enable `https-inspection` Privoxy will impersonate the destination server and can thus filter encrypted requests and responses as well.
>
> Without `https-inspection` secure HTTP connections are encrypted SSL sessions between your browser and the secure site, and there is little that Privoxy can do but hand the raw gibberish data though from one end to the other unprocessed.
>
> The only exception to this is blocking by host patterns, as the client needs to tell Privoxy the name of the remote server, so that Privoxy can establish the connection. If that name matches a host-only pattern, the connection will be blocked.
>
> ***As far as ad blocking is concerned, this is less of a restriction than it may seem, since ad sources are often identifiable by the host name, and often the banners to be placed in an encrypted page come unencrypted nonetheless for efficiency reasons, which exposes them to the full power of Privoxy's ad blocking.***
>
> "Content cookies" (those that are embedded in the actual HTML or JS page content, see `filter{content-cookies}`), in an SSL transaction will be impossible to block under these conditions. Fortunately, this does not seem to be a very common scenario since most cookies come by traditional means.